# Add application in Facebook pages tab/link

Tags: facebook

Is there any way to add applications in Facebook pages dynamically(using api)?

Answer (score 2):

The best thing you can do right now is to redirect to this URL:

```
http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=<your_api_key>&pages
```

(note the `&pages` at the end)

This at least provides a shortcut for them to add the app to one of their pages. Of course not as good as a proper API...

Comment: i saw in some applications after you auth the app, it redirect you to the application itself rather to the page you want the application be added to.

how is it done ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not.  Facebook creates a unique Application ID etc. when you create your application via their site.  There is no access to this process.

Comment: Hi Ardman,

Thanks for reply.

But as i remember earlier this was possible by something like that

http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=xxx

The above URL prompt user to choose a page for requested application.


Has it been removed now?

Comment: @Imran: I have just tried this again and when logged in, it takes me back to my homepage.  So, I would safely say that they have removed it.